# Android Studio hangs on "Tip of the Day"

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, crash

When I start up Android studio, it opens "Tip of the Day", which I cannot close although I can click the X (not the close button though). It says 'Gradle sync started' at the bottom, which never goes away. I attached a screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Try to press "Close" using the "Tab" key in your keyboard. If that happens that's because a bug in JDK 8_60+: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-146691

Comment: @Heisenberg Didn't work but I stopped using a plugin and the problem went away

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Freeze was caused by a plugin in the background not working properly (Team Foundation Server Version Control Integration).

Answer (score 17):

I am on MacOs Big Sur and resolved the issue by going to System preferences >> General >> Prefer tabs "never" when opening documents.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into Android Studio hanging as it started. On the Mac, I was able to resolve the issue by deleting the options file specifying the JDK Studio should use. In my case that file was removed as follows:

```
rm ~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudioPreview3.3/studio.jdk
```

It seems that Android Studio hangs if the specified SDK is too new. Removing the file lets it fall back to its own included JDK.

Answer (score 1):

To solve the problem permanently :-

```
defaults write com.google.android.studio AppleWindowTabbingMode manual
```

Run the above syntax in terminal. Then quit the Android Studio and Restart it.

It solved the issue for me.